# Can a Shia boy marry an ahl e hadith girl in the light of shariah?

Tags: quran, sunnah, shiism, ahlul-hadeeth

AOA!
I am Ali and my question is "can a Shia boy marry an ahl e hadith (Wahhabi) girl"?
I have been asking this question in the light of Quran and hadith. According to the Shia point of view it is legal because it is a marriage between two Muslims. But why this is not considered legal in the eyes of ahl e hadith (Wahabi) school of thought?
Can anybody give me logical reasons for this marriage to be permissible so that I can convey it someone else? I think it is very difficult to get a fatwah. I have looked for many scholars but haven't got the answer.

If anyone knows about any famous ahl e hadith scholar who would grant a fatwah in favour of this marriage then it will be highly appreciated. But I also want logical reasons that this marriage is possible.

JazakAllah!

Comment: No! This isn't a duplicate because ahl e hadith sect is much different than sunni sect. I read this question before (shia-sunni) but my concern was ahl e hadith. 
So please before giving me negative marking just check what I have mentioned there in description. 
Thanks you

Answer (score -1):

Firstly, your query is consisted of diverse queries, so, I assume that’s why nobody has answered it yet, although it seems to be an interesting profitable inquiry. Hence, it would be better if you make it in a short form (in my opinion).

Secondly, I endeavor to reply to it in short.
According to Imam Khomeini (r.a.):

> The marriage between a Shia man with a non-Naasebi Sunni woman is
>   permissible. Note: Nasibis or Naasibi is remarked to a person who has
>   hostility against Ahlul-Bayt or curses (to uses bad language) against
>   them …

According to Ayatollah Khamenei:

> There is no obstacle about that (it is permissible) So, I found almost
>   all the views of Shi’I Marajas the same regarding that. On the other
>   hand, it seems to be a logical issue too, not to get married to
>   Nasibis (as a rational issue)

Note: I prefer not to speak directly about Wahhabis, so, I presented the formula. You can judge, and conclude it (accurately who are Nasibis)

**References and to read more precise/complete issues:**

http://www.tebyan.net/newindex.aspx?pid=227444

[http://www.hawzah.net/fa/Magazine](http://www.hawzah.net/fa/Magazine/View/4227/8018/105190/%D9%86%D8%A7%D8%B5%D8%A8%DB%8C-%DA%A9%DB%8C%D8%B3%D8%AA)

Comment: Well I do have the fatwas of Imam Khamnei and he has also given permission for it. There is also written in the quran that marriage between the ahl e kitab(Book followeres) is permissible. But the Wahabi sect has too much hate for the shias and sunnis as well. So I was looking for a fatwa from a wahabi scholar who allowed this marriage.

Comment: Thank you for your work! 
I have came out of that relationship now. I don't know how and when it happened. But I am thankful to Allah that I am out of it and living a happy married life.